# Primefaces <p:datatable> totalRecords undefined value after Filter

Tags: primefaces, datatable, pagination, filtering

I try to have a totalRecords number (who count the row numbers when filter and no filter) with Primefaces 4.

My Paginator output for the totalRecords number is working until I try to filter the dataTable :

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl_queue" var="c" value="#{productionQueue.cartQueue}" widgetVar="queueTable"
    filteredValue="#{productionQueue.filteredCartQueue}" paginator="true" 
    currentPageReportTemplate="Nb rows: {totalRecords}"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}"> 

    <p:column id="Bumper_column" filterBy="name_bumper" headerText="Bumper"
    filterOptions="#{productionQueue.nameBumperOptionsString}"
    filterMatchMode="exact"
    styleClass="#{productionQueue.determineRowColor(c.date,c.hour)}">

                        <h:outputText value="#{c.name_bumper}" />

    </p:column>

                ... 
</p:datatable>
```

After each update the totalRecords output show me the value : "undefined"

EDIT (Same problem with the PF Showcase example) : 
[image]

But I had to change something to run the example... :
[image]

And... :

[image]

Because when I try to change nothing with the example in Showcase I have this error :

[image]

So finally I think the filter Nb Rows is not working because of the type of Bean (SessionScoped) and I'm blocked with it because I need a SessionScoped in this page to manage my Datatable...

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: No I don't have any javascript error in the Chrome Console.

Comment: The documentation from PrimeFaces 4.0 shows a syntax like yours(filterBy="name_bumper"). However in PrimeFaces 5.0 it's like in 3.4.2(filterBy="#{c.name_bumper}"). For testing you could keep only column and take out the rest of the filter options for the moment to isolate the problem. I cannot test your code right now. Please see if the filterBy syntax for PrimeFaces 5.0 makes any difference.

Comment: If I do like in PF5.0 or 3.4.2 (filterBy="#{c.name_bumper}"), I have already the : "undefined" value and my filter is now not working ... So it's definitely not the solution ^^.

Comment: You could take the code for the pagination and filter examples from PrimeFaces showcase and combine them and see if still have the problem. Could you post the code where you do the filtration?

Comment: Make CarService Serializable for this test. It should work. For your real case you need to provide a simple example(http://sscce.org) that replicates your issue.

Comment: Then, I've exactly the same '@ApplicationScoped' and '@ViewScoped', but it's still not working ('undefined' value...). So it's not the problem. :(.

Comment: In reality, after pressing 'F5' I have the good value instead of 'undefined', but it clear my filter (without broke the filter in the datatable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely caused by some error in the filtering logic.

I have made a small project that combines the pagination and filter examples from PrimeFaces showcase. I used `PrimeFaces 4.0` and `Mojarra JSF 2.2.8`.

Here is the table without applied filters:
[image: DataTable without filters applied]
After I used the filters:
[image: DataTable with filters applied]

When copying the examples from PrimeFaces showcase(it uses `PrimeFaces 5.1`), because filterMatchMode="equals" is not available in PrimeFaces 4.0, I got an error in Tomcat console:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Illegal filter match mode:equals
    at   org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.getFilterConstraint(FilterFeature.java:285)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.filter(FilterFeature.java:130)
```

And in current page info I have your `undefined` value: 
[image: DataTable with wrong filterMatchMode]

Comment: I have no tomcat console error for this undefined value.

Comment: Problem solved : Update Mojarra JSF 2.0.1 to 2.2 solved the problem.